# Аутентификация YouTube Data Api v3

Tags: c#, windows-8, youtube-api

Пытаюсь авторизоваться

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer init = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer();
        ClientSecrets clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
        {
            ClientId = ClientID,
            ClientSecret = ClientSecret
        };
        init.ClientSecrets = clientSecrets;
        init.Scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube };
        myAuthorizationCodeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(init);
        UserCredential credential = null;
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        TokenResponse tokenResponse = myAuthorizationCodeFlow.LoadTokenAsync(ClientID, cancellationToken).FinalResult<TokenResponse>();
        if(tokenResponse!=null)
        {
            credential = new UserCredential(myAuthorizationCodeFlow, ClientID, tokenResponse);
        }

        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer1 = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = myApiKey,
            ApplicationName = myAppName,
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        };
        this.myYoutubeServiceLogged = new YouTubeService(initializer1);

 public static T FinalResult<T>(this Task<T> pTask)
    {
        T result;
        try
        {
            pTask.Wait();
            result = pTask.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = pTask.Result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

tokenResponce постоянно null
В чем ошибка?

Comment: почему Вы просто не используете await flow.LoadTokenAsync(..).ConfigureAwait(false); ?

Comment: Потому, что таким образом могу использовать без "await". Попробовал Вашим методом, тот же null